# Anyway to get data from sqlite db of defunct ios app

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I published an iOS app like a decade ago that used Core Data.  I've since essentially retired from programming, pulled the app out of the store, and I no longer even have the source code.

Someone who has been using the app all this time contacted me - I guess it's been runnable up until the latest upgrade he made - about getting his data out.

Is there any chance of finding the sqlite file on his device or backups and querying it to extract the data or is this a hopeless case?  I feel like a real jerk for creating this situation...

Comment: If the data is not hosted on a server the user can always delete your app. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Maybe using an app like [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer).

Comment: @AnderCover yeah the problem is not wanting to get rid of the data - we want to retrieve it so we can save the data into a spreadsheet or something.... Thanks Tom, we will give that a try!

Comment: I have found the Sqlite database in the app container for the app I was working on. In Xcode, go to Window >> Devices and Simulators, then select the phone in question, then click on the gear symbol. That works for the app which I'm working on in Xcode; maybe it works for other apps. The .sqlite file is somewhere within the app container, you might have to search around for it. Hope this helps.